# Match asterisk followed by space in PCRE

Tags: regex, escaping, expression, pcre

I'm just having trouble figuring out how to regex properly.  What I need is to match an asterisk followed by a space followed by any amount of characters that aren't \n. (Similar to reddit list formatting)

Example:

```
* Test
* Test2
* Test3
```

The closest I got was this, but it wasn't working.

`/^[*][ ](.*?)/s`

Can anyone familiar with PCRE help me.

Comment: remove the s modifier (eventually replace it with the m modifier) and the `?`. look about greedy/non-greedy quantifiers

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a lazy dot pattern at the end of the regex because it will never match any single char (as it will be skipped when the regex engine comes up to it, and since there is nothing to match after it, the empty string will be matched by `.*?`).

Use the greedy dot pattern:

```
^\* (.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHij9I/2)

Other notes: you may use `\h` to match any horizontal whitespace instead of the regular space in the pattern. To match start of lines with `^` use `m` modifier. Only use `s` modifier if you need `.` to match any chars *including* a newline (and carriage return depending on PCRE verbs that are active).